# Will iterating multiple images with CUDA increase performance?

Tags: c++, cuda, nvidia

The code was oversimplified just for the question purpose.
Before I setup CUDA environment and do any changes to my code, I wanted to get an input whether executing the code below will be much faster on GPU.

The code basically iterates through images and copy image pixel value to `dst` only if the corresponding mask value is not zero. Number of images can be as high as 10. The size of the image can be around 2K by 2K.

If I use `#pragma omp` it does increase performance. So, the question is will the performance be significantly increased if I'll execute this code on GPU (assuming I have a good graphic card like GTX 1050) when each thread will handle a separate image?

```
for (int i = 0; i < images.size(); ++i)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < images[i].height; ++y)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < images[i].width; ++x)
        {
            bool maskVal = masks[i][y][x];
            if (maskVal > 0)
            {
                dst[i][y][x] = images[i].data(x,y);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case I would guess not.  That piece of code would probably execute faster if the images and destination were already in the GPUs memory.  However if you plan to take the images and mask from your main memory, copy it over the pci bus, execute the code on the gpu and then transfer the result back to the cpu, you will be much better off just running this code on the cpu.  However if you think you will do further parallel processing to the dst images then you might as well get it transferred to the gpu, and do this on the gpu since you will have to pay that penalty anyway.  The reason openmp is faster is because it uses cpu threads which use the same memory and no extra copying is required.

An example of something which run well on a gpu would be an image convolution or fourier transform since these are tasks are much heavier than what you are doing so the overhead of the memory transfer matters less.